# Saving "array of CustomModes / queryset" inside of a CustomModel works first time, but then throws 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: html, django, django-models

I would like to cut queryset to half and save these 2 querysets to use them later ( I know that this use of queryset (like its done in `Game`) is not valid + it's returned just once, and that's on initialisation (`for game in games` inits, this queryset). If I refresh the site, I get this error. I have been looking around, but I can't find a model, that can store other models / querysets that will last forever

views.py

```
def mm_index(request):
    games = Game.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    for game in games:
        if game.isPrepared:
            queryset = Game.players.order_by('?')[:10]
            Game.team1 = queryset[:5]
            Game.team2 = queryset[5:10]
            game.isReady = True
            game.isPrepared = False
            game.save()
    context = {
        "games": games,
    }
    return render(request, "mm_index.html", context)
```

models.py ( Game )

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
    team1 = models.QuerySet()  # models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser) <- doesnt work
    team2 = models.QuerySet()  # models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser) <- doesnt work
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    isReady = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isPrepared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isFinished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

mm_index.html

```
<tr>
  {% for player in game.team1 %}
     <td>{{ player.lol_username }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
  {% for player in game.team2 %}
    <td>{{ player.lol_username }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

mm_index.html -> throws an error related to `game.team1`, but when i do {{ game }}, it prints Game's `__str__` ( its just a title, not included here )
error message:

```
AttributeError at /mm/
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

The thing I am trying to do here is to cut the queryset to 10 CustomUsers and then cut it on half (5). Then, I want to save it in `Game.team1` and `Game.team2`, to "print it" later on HTML using that Forloop.

Comment: `team1 = models.QuerySet()` I dont think you can save a queryset like this. It wont work. You may use ManyToManyField though. Use `team1.add(player)` to set your team.

Comment: Thanks for an advice, I did so, but the problem is that i am not able to modify it ... Any idea how can i make something that i can later modify? Thanks in advance

Comment: to modify you can use the `add` `remove` `set` and `clear` methods on `ManyToManyField`